# Specifying ymin in pgfplots misalignes images vertically

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment

I have two plots drawn with the `\pgfplots` package. In one of them, I specified that `ymin=0` when I created the `axis` since the plotted curve never goes below y=0 (otherwise something like `ymin=-0.2` would be used). However, when I put both of the plots into two `\subcaptionbox`es that I put in the same `figure` environment, it becomes apparent that this plot has become raised up, since the frame is much higher up for that plot than the frame for the other plot:

[image]

How can I prevent `\pgfplots` from raising up the plot when I specify (hence increasing?) the value of `ymin`? I want the frames of both plots to be aligned vertically.

Comment: Add the code, to help us trying. Anyway, may be you should look at `groupplots` in the documentation (in case you are not using it).

Comment: @Manuel: I figured out the reason for this behavior myself, and it wasn't the `ymin=0` specification that I said it was. See my answer below.

Comment: @Manuel: I updated the answer; I realized my initial explanation was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that it wasn't the `ymin=0` specification that messed up the vertical alignment. This behavior was instead triggered depending on of which sizes the `\subcaptionbox`ex were. It turned out that if they are too large, this misalignment is likely to happen, although I don't really know why.